# Tcl $argc and $argv variables

Tags: variables, tcl, global, argv, argc

I'm kinda new to tcl but I have to write a proc that looks like this:

```
proc TestVerb { Data Data_txt } {
VERBATIM [format "// Data: $Data - $Data_txt"]
if { $argc == 2} {
    VERBATIM {// SUCCESS //}
else {
    exit 1
}
```

I call the proc like this: `TestVerb Switch"This is used for..."`

The proc is in a different file and the proc call is in another one. They seem properly sourced because I get the desired output if I do not use `$argc` but once I use either `$argv` or `$argc` I get the following compilation error: Can't read `$argv/$argc` no such variable

If I refer to this variables with `$::argc` and `$::argv` the result is not correct. `$argv` is empty and $argc is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to make two wrong assumptions here:

- If a proc does not use a special argument `args` in its defintion (see below for more info), it accepts only the fixed number of arguments—exactly matching the number of parameters used in its definition.  Each call is checked by the interpreter, and any call with invalid number of parameters will fail before reaching the procedure's code itself.

  See for yourself:

  ```
  % proc foo {a b c} {}
  % foo
  wrong # args: should be "foo a b c"
  % foo 1
  wrong # args: should be "foo a b c"
  % foo 1 2 3 4
  wrong # args: should be "foo a b c"
  % foo 1 2 3
  %
  ```

  In other words, just don't mess with trying to check the number of arguments passed to your `proc`: it's already checked by the interpreter by the time your procedure is called.
- The `argc` and `argv` global variables control what's passed from the operating system to the Tcl interpreter *program* which is executing your Tcl script.

  That is, when you call something like

  ```
  $ tclsh myscript.tcl foo bar
  ```

  The variable named `argc` will contain 2 and `argv` will be set to the list containing two strings—"foo" and "bar".

  In other words, these variables have nothing to do with individual procedures.

---

Regarding the `args` special argument: if a procedure uses the word "args" for *the last* of its arguments or has it as its sole argument, then this argument is turned into a list which consumes any number (including zero) of actual arguments.

So you can do

```
proc foo {a b args} {}
```

and then your `foo` procedure can be called as both like `foo 1 2` and `foo 1 2 3 4 5 6` but not like `foo x` (because there's no value for the `b` formal argument).

Inside such a proc you use normal list commands (like `llength` and `lindex`) to inspect whatever is contained in `args`.  For instance, the call `foo 1 2 3 4 5 6` would set `args` to the same value you would obtain by calling `[list 3 4 5 6]`.

Answer (score 1):

The `argc` and `argv` variables are global variables (when they have any special meaning). Inside a procedure, they're not special *at all* unless you say:

```
global argc argv
```

or use the fully-qualified versions.

With your procedure, you will get an error message (generated by the procedure call machinery) unless you pass in the right number of arguments. You don't need to check yourself (unless you use formal parameters with defaults or the special `args` variable — note the spelling — at the end of the formal parameters.

To get the exact list of arguments passed in to your procedure, use:

```
set allArguments [info level 0]
```

You normally don't need it. You *definitely* don't need it when declaring your procedure like:

```
proc TestVerb { Data Data_txt } {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for the quick answer. The point is that proc will be used by other people and I need to check the number of arguments they have given to it and if it's not correct to exit; 
I've already tried using 
    global argv argc
But I still get incorrect output:
argv <blank>
argc 0

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned above, `argv` and `argc` do not refer to local procedure arguments,
By default, the number of arguments in a Tcl proc are fixed. If you want to use a variable list, you can write `args`:

```
proc TestVerb {args} {}
```

`args` can be treated as an ordinary list. If you want to test the number of arguments you can use `llength` and use `lassign` to split the argument list:

```
proc TestVerb {args} {
    if {[llength $args] != 2} {
        message
        return
    }
    lassign $args Data Data_txt
    ....
}
```